# Error de sintaxis en MySQL al crear una función

Tags: mysql, sql, funciones, sintaxis

soy nuevo en SQL. Estoy tratando de crear una función que devuelva el número de partidos ganados por un equipo. Pero al ejecutar la función me da error de sintaxis y no veo el error por más vueltas que doy. Este es el código:

```
delimiter //
create function partidos_ganados(equipo int) returns int
    declare victorias_local int;
    declare victorias_visitante int;
    declare victorias_totales int;

    set victorias_local = (select count(*) from partidos where puntosL > puntosV and elocal = equipo);
    set victorias_visitante = (select count(*) from partidos where puntosV > puntosL and evisit = equipo);
    set victorias_totales = (victorias_local + victorias_visitante);

    return(victorias_totales);

end//
delimiter ;
```

El error dice

FAIL:

create function partidos_ganados(equipo int)
returns int
declare victorias_local int;
declare victorias_visitante int;
declare victorias_totales int;
set victorias_local = (select count(*) from partidos where puntosL > puntosV and elocal = equipo);
set victorias_visitante = (select count(*) from partidos where puntosV > puntosL and evisit = equipo);
set victorias_totales = (victorias_local + victorias_visitante); return(victorias_totales);
end;

Message :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare victorias_local int; declare victorias_visitante int; declare victoria' at line 1

Gracias de antemano y disculpad las molestias.

Comment: ***¿Qué versión de MySQL es?***

Comment: ¿Qué dice el error exactamente? Pulsa en [edit] y agrégalo a la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano solucionado :)

Comment: y @MoisesMS si te ha servido la respuesta no te olvides de votarla positivamente :)

Comment: Bien visto @JavierG.Raya, no me percaté de la falta del `BEGIN`.

Comment: Yo no me fije hasta que vi su edición y me percate al ordenar el código @A.Cedano a parte que mis profesores ponen tipo test y dice que falla y le quita el ``;`` o en lugar de poner ``;`` ponen ``: ``  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te falta añadir el ***BEGIN***

```
delimiter //

create function partidos_ganados(equipo int) 
returns int
BEGIN
    declare victorias_local int;
    declare victorias_visitante int;
    declare victorias_totales int;

    set victorias_local = (select count(*) from partidos where puntosL > puntosV and elocal = equipo);
    set victorias_visitante = (select count(*) from partidos where puntosV > puntosL and evisit = equipo);
    set victorias_totales = (victorias_local + victorias_visitante);

    return(victorias_totales);

end //
delimiter ;
```